# how to save a link in my server and load at the button href

Tags: php, html

I have post where it has a download button, and I want to save my download link in a row in my server. So in my site it loads the link in the button.

I made this:

```
 <a href="'.$rows['link'].'" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 " role="button">Download</a>
```

But it does not open my download link.
When I click download it opens the link in my folder as a page, like this:

```
http://localhost/system/adm/www.mylink.com
```

I don't want to save the file in my folders, I want to save in my cloud so I can have huge downloads.

And post this link in my server so the post loads the link in my button.

What is the right way to make this work?

Comment: Can i see how you save the info?

Comment: in my server there is a row called link, the value is www.mylink.com

Comment: Question : do you have any link that starts with "http://"?

Comment: Marc B this is not duplicated, my question is how can i get the link from my row in my server and get the link in the button.

Comment: No i didnt use no https:// in my link, i will test, but im sure that the link wont open, it will open as a page and in my browser will get this link http://localhost/system/adm/www.mylink.com

Comment: It works with https://              thx @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links open locally if they don't have "http://" at the beginning, so just add it to all your links :

```
           ▼
<a href='http://" . $rows['link'] . "' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Download</a>
```